# Python : name 'math' is not defined Error?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and cant understand why this is happening:

```
from math import *
print "enter the number"
n=int(raw_input())
d=2
s=0
while d<n :
    if n%d==0:
       x=math.log(d)
       s=s+x
       print d
    d=d+1
print s,n,float(n)/s
```

Running it in Python and inputing a non prime gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\mit ocw\pset1a.py", line 28, in <module>
    x=math.log(d)
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Comment: About modules: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Change

```
from math import *
```

to

```
import math
```

Using `from X import *` is generally not a good idea as it uncontrollably pollutes the global namespace and could present other difficulties.

Comment: ohh i was actually studying using MIT OCW and in their problem set it was written to use from math import *

Comment: @Danny: I don't know why they chose to write it that way, but I'd advise against using `from X import *`.

Comment: @Danny: In some cases importing using `*` is reasonable, but as @aix said, it " _is generally not a good idea_ ". So for simple scripts you will not be expanding you may not care, but for more complex ones you should care.

Comment: What are some of the other difficulties?

Comment: @MattFenwick: Mainly the inability to reload() things imported in this manner.

Answer (score 10):

You did a mistake..

When you wrote :

```
from math import *
# This imports all the functions and the classes from math
# log method is also imported.
# But there is nothing defined with name math
```

So, When you try using `math.log`

It gives you error, so :

replace `math.log` with `log`

Or

replace `from math import *` with `import math`

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You need to `import math` rather than `from math import *`.

Answer (score 1):

How about (when you need only `math.pi`):

```
from math import pi as PI
```

and then use it like `PI` symbol?