# Factorial Command in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

How does one use the factorial command in Python?  I have attempted the `math.factorial` command, and either I am using it completely incorrectly, or it isn't working and returns the error

```
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

for some reason.

Comment: Possibly also related: [Python : name 'math' is not defined Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8329601), if you used `from math import *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the math module first:

```
import math
math.factorial(x)
```

Comment: Is there another method with which to calculate a factorial progression without using the math.factorial(x) command?

Comment: @Josh: [Function for Factorial in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5136447)

Comment: @Josh What's wrong with the `math` module?  I'm always curious when I see requests to avoid using the standard library.

Comment: @SethMMorton  If I'm being honest, it would be because I am learning Python in a Comp Sci class and it hasn't been covered so I'm a bit on the fence about whether to use it or not.  I was trying to figure out how to complete it using commands that we were taught, but have since figured out that I have these 'textbooks' and 'useful links' that were provided by the professor for a reason.  That is why I was attempting to avoid the standard library.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  If you look at the post above, you will notice the reason why I was unable to put together the asin() post that you referred to previously as having already answered this question as being related.  That being said, I am truly appreciative of everything that you two have explained.