# Why does this python code gives runtime error?

Tags: python, runtime-error, primes

```
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,math.sqrt(n)):
        if n%i ==0 :
            return False

    return True



#limits calculated using prime number theory by hand
primes=[]
for num in range(104319,114319):
    if isPrime(num):
        primes.append(num)
```

I am using Ideone.

This is the error

> Runtime error time: 0.03 memory: 9984 signal:-1
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./prog.py", line 13, in
>      File "./prog.py", line 2, in isPrime NameError: name 'math'
>   is not defined

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Comment: The `range()` function requires integer values. `range(2,math.sqrt(n))` won't work.

Comment: Visually, you have an issue with `range(2,math.sqrt(n))` since the second argument is a float, not the required `int`

Comment: Add `import math` at the top....

Comment: You need to `import math`.

Comment: Doesn't work even if use floor function

Comment: @UtkarshMittal Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think you will find some good ideas that will help you get better answers to your questions and to ask better questions that get voted up. Your question was probably voted down because you did not [search](https://www.google.com/#q=NameError%3A+name+%27math%27+is+not+defined) for [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8329617). Also you might enjoy reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives you that error, because you forgot to import `math`.  Even if you do, however, you will still have an error because `range()` expects an integer argument and `math.sqrt()` returns a `float`.  Also, you need to go one higher than the square root because the second argument to `range()` is exclusive.  You can do this:

```
import math

def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False

    return True



#limits calculated using prime number theory by hand
primes=[]
for num in range(104319,114319):
    if isPrime(num):
        primes.append(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

`math.sqrt` returns a float object, but `range` needs an `int` object. You should do

```
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))+1): #Convert the result of math.sqrt to int
        if n%i ==0 :
            return False
    return True
```

Edit: After your edit "NameError: name 'math' is not defined", you should import math at the begining

```
import math

def isPrime(n):
#...
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this fixes the runtime error but doesn't fix isPrime() which still passes 4, 8, 9, 15, etc. as primes.

Comment: @cdlane Right, upper limit on range increased by one to check all number until `sqrt(n)` included. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code you need to import the module you are calling like this

```
import math
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix your code.

```
import math

def isprime(n):
     for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))):
          if n%i == 0:
               return False
          else:
               return True
```

Comment: This fixes the OP's range() arguments, but it doesn't fix his code.  This isprime() routine seems to believe that 9, 15, 21, 25, 27, 33, etc. are primes.  The OP had it better with the `return True` after the loop, though still wrong.