# i have this program that i did but for some reason its not importing math, please help and let me know what is wrong with it

Tags: python

```
from math import sqrt
def f(x) :
    print("f(x) call g(x)= ", g(x))
    print( "f(x) call sqrt(h(x)) = ", sqrt(h(x)))
    print ()
    return g(x) + math.sqrt(h(x))

def g(x) :
    return 4 * h(x)           
    print("g(x) call h(x)= ", h(x))
    
def h(x) :
    return x * x + k(x) - 1 
 #   print("h(x) call k(x)= ", k(x))

def k(x) :
    return 2 * (x + 1) 
  #  print("k(x) call, 2 * (x+1) = ", 2 * (x +1))

x1 = f(2)
print("x1 = ",x1)
print ()

x2 = g(h(2)) 
print("x2 = ",x2)
print ()

x3 = k(g(2) + h(2)) 
print("x3 = ",x3)
print ()

x4 = f(0) + f(1) + f(2)

print("x4 = ",x4)
print ()

x5 = f(-1) + g(-1) + h(-1) + k(-1) 
print("x5 = ",x5)
print ()
```

The error what I get:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-d083b9e93ab7> in <module>()
     18   #  print("k(x) call, 2 * (x+1) = ", 2 * (x +1))
     19 
---> 20 x1 = f(2)
     21 print("x1 = ",x1)
     22 print ()

<ipython-input-28-d083b9e93ab7> in f(x)
      4     print( "f(x) call sqrt(h(x)) = ", sqrt(h(x)))
      5     print ()
----> 6     return g(x) + math.sqrt(h(x))
      7 
      8 def g(x) :

NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi. Could you please format your code properly? It's hard to read this way. It looks to me as if you simply forgot a newline after your import statement.

Comment: this is probably because you have another file called math in the same directory

Comment: Just use `import math` the statement `from math import sqrt` is essentially equivalent to `import math; sqrt = math.sqrt; del math`, so it removes the module from the namespace, and only keeps the names you designate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : name 'math' is not defined Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329601/python-name-math-is-not-defined-error)

Comment: Read the documentation and examples on using `import`.  The problem is that you imported `sqrt` individually; you did *not* import `math`.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to actually import math first! you imported sqrt from math, but it hasn't defined math yet so it doesn't know what to do.

add a simple

```
import math
```

to the beginning of your code and it should run!

Comment: @Giuppox no, *it shouldn't*. This is a correct answer.

Comment: They can also just remove the `math.` from the calls to `sqrt`...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
return g(x) + math.sqrt(h(x))
```

to

```
return g(x) + sqrt(h(x))
```

Comment: thank you so much, can you please explain why it worked when i removed the "math" so i have better understanding of the issue

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html